# deselecting cells that are currently not visible

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, deselect

I'm trying to deselect cells that were previously selected but are not currently visible in collection view. I'm using this code:

```
        let optionalSelectedItems = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems()
        if let selectedItems = optionalSelectedItems{
        for indexPath in selectedItems{

         self.collectionView.deselectItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
         self.collectionView.delegate?.collectionView!(self.collectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath: indexPath)
        }
```

There is some pretty important stuff going on in my implementation of `func collectionView(_:didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:)`. Deselection triggers an event in some other view.
This throws an error because I am deselecting cells that are currently off screen and hence not even in the memory. How do I put cells in the memory for just a brief period of time? I only need to deselect them so I'm guessing 0.1s would be more than enough.

Comment: I had similar problem with `UITableView`; the solution was to call `super.tableView:deselectRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: some pretty important stuff happens in my implementation of collectionView(_:didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:) and it needs to be called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store indexes of selected rows in separate array and select/deselect cells after creation in

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

Comment: I am deselecting all cells when I press a specific button. Correct me if I am wrong, but that method will never be called, because it is called only when cell becomes visible.

Comment: then how you can touch the button on the cell "that are currently not visible"?

Comment: The button is NOT a cell. It is a normal UIButton instance somewhere outside of collection view.

Comment: ok, then my answer should be correct, if cell is not visible then it's not exists, so you should save indexes of selected cell in separate array and manage it independently. To sync it with UI you should use "cellForItemAtIndexPath" method.

Comment: there are 2 situations. 1: I scroll the collection view to find out if a cell is selected.  2: I don't scroll but the cell still gets deselected. Deselecting cells trigger an event which takes place in another UIView. That event must happen at the exact moment the button is pressed and it is implemented in collectionView(_:didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:). "cellForItemAtIndexPath" will trigger this event when the cell because visible, too late for me.

Comment: you can't deselect cell if it's not visible, because it not exists. 
My idea that cells - it's UI only, and you don't need it to manage if your OBJECT is selected or not. You can manage if the OBJECT is selected by using additional separate array,  where you will store the indexes of all selected objects. And your logic will work with this array only.
To show your users in UI if the object in table is selected you cam mark it as selected in cellForItemAtIndexPath method